# How do I disable usage reporting in the Google Cloud SDK (gcloud)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

The Google Cloud SDK collects anonymized metrics on usage in order to help the team better understand how to prioritize the development of new features and improvements.

While I can select whether to enable usage reporting at installation time, how can I turn it off later if I change my mind?

Answer (score 10):

If you've decided that you no longer want your install of the Google Cloud SDK to send usage data, you can run the following command:

```
gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting true
```

To *enable* metrics, run the following:

```
gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting false
```

This information can be found in the install-time output:

> Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
>
> To help improve the quality of this product, we collect anonymized data on how the SDK is used. You may choose to opt out of this collection now (by choosing 'N' at the below prompt), or at any time in the future by running the following command:
>
> ```
> gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting true
> ```

For more information, see the [Usage Statistics](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/usage-statistics) page on the Google Cloud SDK website.